# Can I use the prefix "Non-" instead of other negative prefixes?

Tags: word-usage, difference, synonyms, negation

Would there be any difference? 
For instance,

> 1. I don't want to talk about non-important issues. (unimportant)
> 2. He is a very non-active/non-sexual person.  (inactive) (asexual)
> 3. This is a non-logical assumption.  (illogical)

Comment: In short, no.  People would understand what you meant, but it's neither idiomatically nor grammatically correct to substitute "non-" for other, established negative prefixes.

Comment: You mean *"he is non-present today"*?

Comment: @MaulikV - Actually, "he is not present today" would be more likely.

Answer (score 1):

The prefix **non-** is used with words that either don't have a form with "another" negative prefix or an antonym, like

> **non**-issue.
>   **non**-denominational church

or with words for which the standard form (or the antonym) has a slightly different meaning from what can be achieved by using '**non**-'

> A **non**-negative value - (="positive ***or*** zero" instead of "*positive*")

The rest should be used with the "regular" negative prefix.